# MySQL Find timeslot confliction

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find time slot conflicts in an sql database. An example fo the table is:

```
id | startTime | endTime
---+-----------+---------
1  | 09:00:00  | 10:00:00
2  | 10:00:00  | 10:20:00
```

The statement I'm working is meant to return how many slots the proposed one will conflict with, it is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE (endTime > #{start} AND endTime <= #{end}) OR (startTime >= #{start} AND startTime < #{end})
```

But this doesn't account for time slots inside of existing slots, such as if I try to book a slot from `09:15` to `09:45`, the system won't detect the conflict with the first slot.

Another design requirement is that if one slot finishes at `11:00` and another starts at the same time, there aren't any conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the new slot is (start,end) = (s2,e2), break down the problem to smaller/simpler ones:

1. Check if the s2 falls inside a time slot, ie:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE (endTime > s2 AND startTime < s2)
   ```
2. Check if the e2 time falls into a time slot:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE (endTime > e2 AND startTime < e2)
   ```

The above two are definitely conflicts and take care of all cases where a time *portion* overlaps. However, it does not check if the new slot (s2,e2) wraps around an existing slot, so

3. see if an existing slot falls into our new one:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE (endTime < e2 AND startTime > s2)
   ```

You can combine all three in a single query (using OR) and I think it should work (not tested). Equality has been removed to take care of slots finishing and starting at the same time

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE 
(endTime > #{start} AND startTime < #{start}) 
OR 
(endTime > #{end} AND startTime < #{end})
OR
(endTime < #{end} AND startTime > #{start})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE 
(startTime > #{end} AND endTime > #{end}) 
OR 
(startTime < #{start} AND endTime < #{start})
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you are doing is correct only slite condition changes as follows:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Slots WHERE endTime <#{start} AND startTime > #{end}

Hope this help you, have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest logic is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Slot
WHERE endTime > #{start} AND startTime < #{end}
```

I'm not sure if the correct logic is `>` or `>=`.  The logic is simple:  two time periods overlap when one starts before the second ends, and the first ends after the second starts.